# Passing text box data to stored proc and returning it to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Wondering where I'm going wrong here. I'm page loads but when I click on the search (after I type something in the last name field) it just clocks and clocks.

Here's my aspx.cs page:

> ```
> using System;
> using System.Collections;
> using System.Configuration;
> using System.Data;
> using System.Web;
> using System.Web.Security;
> using System.Web.UI;
> using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
> using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
> using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
> using System.Data.SqlClient;
>
>   public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
>     {
>     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>
>     }
>
>     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         DataSet ds = new DataSet();
>
>         using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("SERVER=ServerName;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=DBNAME"))
>         {
>             using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
>             {
>                 cmd.CommandText = "customerSearchStoredProc";
>                 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
>                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lName", lNameTextbox.Text);
>                 cmd.Connection = con;
>
>                 SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
>                 adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
>                 adapter.Fill(ds);
>
>             }
>             con.Close();
>         }
>         GridView1.DataSource = ds;
>         GridView1.DataBind();
>
>         /*SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("customerSearchStoredProc", con);
>         adp.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
>         adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lName", System.Data.SqlDbType.Text));
>         //adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@State", System.Data.SqlDbType.Text));
>         adp.SelectCommand.Parameters["@lName"].Value = lNameTextbox.Text;
>         //adp.SelectCommand.Parameters["@State"].Value = StateTextbox.Text;
>
>         adp.Fill(ds);
>         GridView1.DataSource = ds;
>         GridView1.DataBind();*/
>
>
>     }
>
>     protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>
>     }
> }
> ```

Here's my aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %> <%@ OutputCache Duration="1" VaryByParam="none" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" > <head runat="server">
    <title>MSS Archive Page</title> </head> <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="Last Name"  runat="server" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="lNameTextbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" Text="First Name"  runat="server" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="fName" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
       <!-- <asp:Label ID="Label3" Text="Street"  runat="server" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="Street" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" Text="City"  runat="server" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="City" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" ></asp:TextBox> -->
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" Text="State" runat="server" />&nbsp;<!-- <asp:TextBox ID="State" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox> -->
        <asp:TextBox ID="StateTextbox" runat="server" ReadOnly="True">MA</asp:TextBox>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label6" Text="Zip"  runat="server" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="Zip" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Search" OnClick="Button1_Click"  /><br />
        OR<br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label7" Text="Policy"  runat="server" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="Policy" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label8" Text="Account"  runat="server" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="Account" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;<br />
        &nbsp;<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnDataBinding="Button1_Click" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" >

        </asp:GridView>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
        &nbsp; &nbsp;
        &nbsp;&nbsp;

    </form> </body> </html>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What happens if you run the stored proc manually (ie from sql management studio)?

Comment: What happens when you execute the stored proc from SQL Server management Studio?  How many results do you get back?  It could be nothing wrong in your code, and at the SQL end, or it could be you're just getting so many results the page is taking forever to load..

Comment: OnDataBinding="Button1_Click" ?? Is that really what you want..

Comment: Good catch by Pleun, I suspect that is the cause of your looping...

Comment: Hmmm, when I run the stored proc in SQL DB MGR I get 171 rows in 2 secs.

Comment: Good catch Pleun, I took out the OnDataBinding, but now it doesn't post back anything to the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your databinding is calling the on click.

```
OnDataBinding="Button1_Click"
```

In the on click you call databind.

```
GridView1.DataBind();
```

To me that looks like a loop going on forever.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. The OnDataBinding was hanging me up. It doesn't clock for ever now. New problem though. It doesn't post the data to the screen.

Comment: Look at David Strattons answer: put AutoGenerateColuns = "true" or add some columns explicitly

Answer (score 2):

I see that the GridView has no columns explicitly defined, and you've got AutoGenerateColumns = false.

Is that an omission from the code, or is your code really like that? If so, then the GridView won't show anything.  Try setting AutoGenerateColuns = "true" and see if anything shows up.  If so, then the problem is you need to explicitly define your columns.

Comment: Great that did it! Thanks for your help! I can't make both answers the correct answer unfortunately. I'll repost that second question if you'd like.

Comment: No, accept @Pleun's answer.  He caught the problem that was causing an endless loop.  Cheers!

Comment: Alright thanks David. You guys have been very helpful. I have another question, but I don't want to lose my good resources so I'll ask it here. Let me know if I should start another one. How do I do postbacks and sorting? I click on page 2 of my results and nothing. I'm going to revisit my code now, but I just wanted to throw that out there. Thanks.